# R httr::GET error Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: r, ssl, curl, get, httr

I've been developing some apps which use my organization's development api. So we're now ready to turn out development work into production. Part of that includes the api itself. The development URL is something like "http://oceanecono1.web806.discountasp.net/api/Ocean/DataYears". This example just returns the years in which data is available; other api endpoints allow for data queries. The production api URL is "https://oceaneconomics.org/api/Ocean/DataYears". The api itself works fine. However, when I query the production url using
httr::GET(url = "https://oceaneconomics.org/api/Ocean/DataYears",verbose())
I get an error, "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : Failure when receiving data from the peer"

I'm using R 4.2.3 on a Windows computer. I tried the same code on my Linux computer and got a different error "Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading, errno 0  >"

The problem seems to be with SSL in the httr library. Does anyone know whether is there is a configuration setting or package (or update of a package) which will let httr::GET read from an https url? Are there other workarounds?  Thanks in advance.

I tried installing the openssl package and some httr configuration settings I found on the web. None of these worked. The literature regarding httr and ssl seems pretty sparse. I haven't found much documentation on this topic at all. I also tried another way of retrieving data: fromJSON(url("https://oceaneconomics.org/api/Ocean/DataYears"))

The returned the following error:
Error in readBin(3L, raw(0), 32768L) : cannot read from connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readBin(3L, raw(0), 32768L) :
URL 'https://oceaneconomics.org/api/Ocean/DataYears': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'

I'm not ruling out issues with our server at this point. However, when I pate the example url into a browser, I get a JSON formatted list the years for which our data is available. Which is what I'd expect.